# How to click/select radio button with python/selenium

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, xpath, radio-button

I've been trying to automatize a report with python/selenium from a webpage. Right now I'm stock trying to select a radio button. Could you please help me with this issue, and if is possible some tips to make the code look/work better.

I'm using XPath Helper to identify XPaths but I'm getting a "Null" value for this:

```
//*[@id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbUseSpecifiedDeviceConfiguration"]
```

**This is the error message that I get when I run the code:**

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbUseSpecifiedDeviceConfiguration']"}
```

**webpage code**

```
<div class="indent">
                    <div>
                        <input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbUseDeviceDefaultConfigurations" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gnConfigurationType" value="rbUseDeviceDefaultConfigurations" checked="checked"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbUseDeviceDefaultConfigurations">Default Device Configurations</label>
                    </div>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <span class="hasValidation"><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbUseSpecifiedDeviceConfiguration" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gnConfigurationType" value="rbUseSpecifiedDeviceConfiguration" onclick="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rbUseSpecifiedDeviceConfiguration\',\'\')', 0)"><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbUseSpecifiedDeviceConfiguration">Specify Device Configuration...</label></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="indent">

                    </div>
                    <div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="indent">

                    </div>
                </div>
```

**Python code**

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#Opens Chrome driver and maximize window
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\Python27\selenium\webdriver\chrome\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()

# Username and password for webpage
username = 'XXX'    #username to login in to web app
password = 'YYY'    #Password to login in to web app

# Gets webpage
driver.get('https://www.XXX-YYY.com/')

# Automatized script to get from main page to Trending
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='_GlobalLoginControl_UserLogin']")   # Fills username textBox
search_box.send_keys(username)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='_GlobalLoginControl_Password']")    # Fills password textBox
search_box.send_keys(password)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='_GlobalLoginControl_LoginBtn']")    # Click login Button
search_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='8:45']/ins")                        # treeBtn
search_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='8:218']/ins")                       # treeBtn
search_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='8:581']/ins")                       # Trending treeBtn
search_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='a8:583']")                          # tag
search_box.click()
time.sleep(6)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pageheading_menu_anchor']")             # Related pages dropDownList
search_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='pageheading_menu_anchor_panel_s1_l4']")         # Quick trending tag
search_box.click()
time.sleep(6)
##############################
### My issue is below this ###
##############################
search_box = driver.find_element_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbUseSpecifiedDeviceConfiguration']")        # Specify Device Configuration radioBtn
search_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DeviceTrendCfgSelector_ConfigurationListAnchor']/img")        # Select Configuration dropDownList
search_box.click()
time.sleep(2)
search_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_DeviceTrendCfgSelector_ConfigurationList']/div/a[3]")         # 4 lease operator with memos and choke size
search_box.click()
```

Comment: Check whether radio-button located inside an `iframe`

Comment: Yes it is in an iFrame

Comment: then first you need to switch into frame and then click on radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should switch to `iframe` before handling radio-button:

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
search_box = driver.find_element_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rbUseSpecifiedDeviceConfiguration']")        # Specify Device Configuration radioBtn
search_box.click()
```

Comment: Thanks for the info... It did not work :(... still looking for more info about iFrames... Thanks!

Comment: There might be more `iframes` on page. Share `HTML` for target `iframe`

Comment: I found the issue, I was using single quotation marks instead of double

**This was the right one**

`driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))`